# How to split an m4v file?

Tags: itunes, video-editing, m4v

I downloaded a TV season on iTunes (.m4v files), however the files are clustered into 3 episodes each.  I'd like to chop these up so that each episode is in it's own file.  Googling around a while didn't provide any promising leads.

What's the easiest way to split these files up?

**Update:** Yes, the files are DRM'd.

Comment: You may not be able to if you bought them from iTunes store as they will possibly be DRM'd

Comment: Even still, there has to be a way to split the files though, right?

Comment: I doubt that you will be able to split the files while leaving the DRM intact.

Comment: Is there no free software capable of stripping the DRM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really the most user friendly software, but [SUPER](http://www.erightsoft.com/SUPER.html) can do the job, and it's free.

Comment: "Not the most user friendly" might just win understatement of the year... but as the only option, to the victor goes the spoils.

Comment: @Chris: Cheers! Yeps, from the looks of it, the UI seems like it's "designed" by a coder ;-)